# Creating new Java object instantiation error

Tags: clojure

I am trying to create a new SimpleLinkResolver in Clojure. This is the JavaDoc:

http://prismicio.github.io/java-kit/io/prismic/SimpleLinkResolver.html

My clojure code is:

```
(def lr (new io.prismic.SimpleLinkResolver))
```

but at the repl I get the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.InstantiationException, compiling:(form-init460449823042827832.clj:1:1)
```

I have no problem creating a java.util.Date:

```
(def d (new java.util.Date))
=> #'prismic-clojure.core/d
d
=> #inst"2018-03-17T10:30:36.016-00:00"
```

The above JavaDoc does say that SimpleLinkResolver is deprecated because the interface LinkResolver (http://prismicio.github.io/java-kit/io/prismic/LinkResolver.html) has default methods and so can be implemented directly. So I gave this a go to:

```
(def lr (new io.prismic.LinkResolver))
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for interface io.prismic.LinkResolver,
```

And I get this "no ctor" error - which I am guessing means the compiler can't find a constructor?

**Questions:**

1. Why does the first effort produce an InstantiationException?
2. Not being familiar with the Java-8 default methods, how would I create a new LinkResolver using its default methods?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the first effort produce an InstantiationException?

You can't instantiate an abstract class:

```
public abstract class SimpleLinkResolver
```

> Not being familiar with the Java-8 default methods, how would I create a new LinkResolver using its default methods?

You'll need to implement `LinkResolver` interface, which can be done using Clojure's `reify`:

```
(def resolver
  (reify LinkResolver
    (^String resolve [this ^Fragment$DocumentLink link]
      "a string"))) ;; put actual impl. here
(.resolve resolver nil)
;; => "a string"
```

Note you need to type-hint the return value (and arguments) because `.resolve()` is an overloaded method.

Also, you typically see `(Class.)` dot-syntax rather than `(new Class)` to instantiate Java classes.

Comment: thank you for your very informative answer. Much appreciated!